# Poder acceder a una pagina creada con Laravel desde cualquier PC

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, he creado un proyecto en Laravel para un trabajo, y por primera vez me resulta necesario que se pueda acceder al proyecto desde cualquier ordenador (vamos, como con esta misma página web).
Me gustaria saber de que forma puedo adaptar mi proyecto de Laravel a una pagina web real. Ademas, sera necesario que le de un nombre normal, en vez del `localhost/(nombre del proyecto)/public/`.

Actualizo: Me he ido a una página de hosts llamada `000webhost File Manager`. Me he creado una cuenta de usuario, he creado un sitio web creado `ficherodejuegos` y ahora me encuentro aqui:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La historia ahora es como hago para que mi carpeta con el proyecto de laravel sea subido. Puedo subir ficheros individuales, pero no se como subir carpetas enteras.

Más datos: Ya descargue Filezilla, y me encuentro con que tengo que rellenar unos parametros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece ser que tengo que poner información de mi sitio web, pero no lo entiendo bien y me da error. ¿Alguien me aclara que hago?

Más cosas: He utilizado Filezilla, pasandole datos de mi host en 000webhost:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque parece que hay algun error debido a dificultades con caracteres ASCII, parece que al fin se ha hecho conexión.
Ahora lo que queda meter en esa zona llamada `public_html`, pero no se como meter toda una carpeta dentro. ¿Debo comprimir previamente el proyecto?

Comment: y porque no lo subes a hosting y listo? y no te complicas la vida configurando el servidor apache2 para que funcione asi?

Comment: @Simon ¿Hosting? No lo conozco. Puede ser una opción. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: a un hosting web

Comment: Vere que hago, pero a ver si es algo gratuito.

Comment: No es que adaptes tu proyecto laravel, es que lo subas a un servidor web, lo cual es necesario

Comment: @AlfredoPaz eso le comente.

Comment: He actualizado mi pregunta.

Comment: o lo subes a través de git(si es que tu servidor lo permite) o lo subes a través de un gestor como filezilla

Comment: Diria que la mejor opción es Filezilla. ¿Alguien tiene un video en el que se explique paso a paso como se pasa a la web el proyecto de laravel con este programa?

Comment: Una vez abierto el filezilla debes de pasar la carpeta de la siguiente forma: en la izquierda localizas tu carpeta local; en la derecha abres la carpeta public_html; arrastras la carpeta de la izquierda a la derecha dentro de public_html; una vez hecho esto podras acceder a xxx.000webhosts.com/[nombre carpeta laravel]

Answer (score 1):

voy a explicarte los pasos que debes realizar para subir un sitio web a un hosting cualquiera.

Primero debes de localizar tus datos FTP, dependiendo del hosting que utilizes dichos datos los encontraras en un sitio u en otro, dado tu ejemplo namás logearte en la página y hacer clic en detalles del sitio web en cuestión lo puedes visualizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu filezilla debarás poner el Host, el usuario y la contraseña (la misma con la que accedes a 000webhost)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La mísma página 000webhost te proporciona toda la información que necessitas en inglés. Debes de subir tus archivos (es decir tu carpeta entera de laravel) dentro de public_html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usas los mismos detalles para acceder al phpmyadmin o haces clic a manage databases

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creas una nueva base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La abres con phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez estas dentro, entras en la base de datos local en tu ordenador donde tienes enlazado el laravel y exportas la base de datos, esto te generará un script sql el cual lo lanzas en el phpmyadmin de 000webhost y ya tendrás la base de datos montada, una vez hecha la copia de la base de datos editas el archivo de laravel para que apunte a la neuva base de datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, cualquier duda comentas.
Saludos.

Comment: Ya he entrado en el modo phpmyadmin del 000host. Dices que tengo que importar mi base de datos. Supongo que para ello exporto la BBDD del phpmyadmin de mi localhost y tras exportarlo lo importo en el otro.

Comment: De hecho, me he fijado que en mi BBDD en 000webhost en vez de "juego" se tiene que llamar "id6581074_juego". ¿Debo hacer el cambio en el fichero .env de mi proyecto?

Comment: Con los pasos que me has explicado he avanzado un poco. He actualizado mi pregunta.

Comment: Ya logre arreglar esto. Ahora tengo lios para imprimir en PDF.

Comment: Si debes renombrar en e fichero de laravel el idxxx_juego que es el nombre real de la BBDD. Tambien tienes que exportar la BBDD de tu localhost y importarlo al 000webhost.